# Visual Studio 2012 Update 5 available but will not install

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Today Visual Studio 2012 prompted me to install Update 5 but when I click on it I get redirected to default Microsoft download page and there I cannot find any VS 2012 Update 5, only VS 2013 Update 5. What is wrong?

Comment: Have the same problem. Seems like the prompt was by mistake. This page says that Update 4 is the latest update for VS2012 at the moment. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39305

Comment: PS Here is a link to Update 5 RC. But note, it is Release Candidate. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48125

Comment: Yes, I have seen this one too, but RC only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the correct link
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48708

Comment: Error 404 - Not found
We're sorry, this download is no longer available.